# Xamarin equivalent to WebAuthenticationBroker GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, adal

I am trying authenticate a Xamarin Forms app but I cannot find an alternative to the Windows namespace class and method: WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri.

For the Xamarin Forms UWP app I can use it to the get the RedirectURL, but I'm not sure what to do about the iOS and Android apps.

```
    class Authenticator : IAuthenticator
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Address to return to upon receiving a response from the authority.
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly Uri RedirectURI = WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri();


    public async Task<AuthenticationResult> AuthenticateAsync(UserLogOn user, string authority, string resource, Uri redirectURI, string clientId)
    {
        PlatformParameters platformParams = new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always, false);

        try
        {

            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

            var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, RedirectURI, platformParams);
            return authResult;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"AquireTokenAsync Error: {e.Message}");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you,
Mark

Comment: As it is right now, it is difficult to provide a good question since some details are missing. Which library are you using for authentication? `Xamarin.Auth`? Is the code you are showing for UWP?

Comment: Yes that is the UWP code, and I'm using ADAL: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory. Xamarin.Auth doesn't look like it has been touched in over two years, so I'm not sure I want to use it. But I'm flexible. The main thing is, I need a token back which has all of the proper information, and the GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri method apparently associates the app's Window Store ID and RedirectURL together. So, for the iOS and Android app's I think I need to figure out how to use the GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri method from within iOS and Android.

Comment: @MarkGarcia Just a side note, I know the Xamarin Auth library is confusing since there is an old one out there but [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Auth/) version does get regular updates.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know hvaughan3. I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had a permissions issue with our Azure AD account, but once that was resolved this is the solution for Android and iOS that I ended up using:

Adding this Redirect URI to Azure AD App Registration and substituting it for the Windows only method GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri did the trick.

```
/// <summary>
/// Redirect URI for Android and iOS.
/// </summary>
public static Uri RedirectURI = new Uri("http://AppNamespace.azurewebsites.net/local");
```

Here, I used an interface within the projects:

Android

```
class Authenticator : IAuthenticator
{
    public async Task<AuthenticationResult> AuthenticateAsync(UserLogOn user, string authority, string resource, Uri redirectURI, string clientId)
    {
        try
        {
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

                var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, redirectURI, new PlatformParameters((Activity)Forms.Context));

                return authResult;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

iOS

```
class Authenticator : IAuthenticator
{
    public async Task<AuthenticationResult> AuthenticateAsync(UserLogOn user, string authority, string resource, Uri redirectURI, string clientId)
    {
        try
        {
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

            var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, redirectURI,
                new PlatformParameters(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController));

            return authResult;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

And then finally I used this line to call interface:

```
var authResult = await DependencyService.Get<IAuthenticator>().AuthenticateAsync(user, QueryParameters.Authority, QueryParameters.GraphResourceUri, QueryParameters.RedirectURI, QueryParameters.ClientId);
```